# Type-hinting method's return type which is one of a set of values passed to class initaliser

Tags: python, generics, python-3.10, python-3.11, python-3.12

I'm refactoring [an OSS library](https://pypi.org/project/phx-filters/) to add better type hinting support, and I'm running into a challenge annotating the return type for a method, where the type will be one of the types passed in an iterable to the class constructor.

Here's a trimmed-down version of the class:

```py
import typing

AllowedType = typing.TypeVar('AllowedType')

class Type(typing.Generic[AllowedType]):
    def __init__(self,
        allowed_types:
            typing.Type[AllowedType] | typing.Iterable[typing.Type[AllowedType]]
    ):
        try:
            self.allowed_types = tuple(allowed_types)
        except TypeError:
            self.allowed_types = (allowed_types,)

    def apply(self, value: typing.Any) -> AllowedType:
        assert isinstance(value, self.allowed_types)
        return value

# ✅ PyCharm correctly infers that ``must_be_int`` type is ``int``.
must_be_int = Type(int).apply(42)

# ❌ PyCharm incorrectly infers that ``must_be_str_or_int`` type is ``Any``.
# It should be ``str | int`` instead.
must_be_str_or_int = Type((str, int)).apply(42)
```

How do I annotate `allowed_types` so that my IDE correctly infers the return type of the `apply` method when a class instance is initialised with a collection of allowed types?

I've committed to supporting the three latest versions of Python for this library, so ideally the solution 'just works' in Python 3.10, 3.11, and 3.12 (or uses [typing_extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/)).